# APK file to stream

Tags: android, apk, inputstream

When I try to stream an APK file `apkPath.inputStream()`
I receive the error `(Is a directory)`.

However, Google has a [demo](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/f0edd38359f17724ac214f179c16edc414003236/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/InstallApkSessionApi.java) where `getAssets().open(assetName)` is used on an asset that is an APK, to install it, where `getAssets().open(assetName)` returns an input stream.

Does anyone have advice or useful resources on how to stream an APK?

Comment: What does "stream an APK file" mean? What is `apkPath`? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I am taking an <app>.apk file, and using it for an input stream. apkPath is the path to that file.

Comment: "apkPath is the path to that file" -- apparently not, based on your reported error.

Comment: The app.apk file is copied to an SD card, then inserted into the Android device. The path is `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), apk_name `. Is that not correct?

Comment: You seem to be confusing [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: You are correct, sir. I am. Thanks!